# Interceptar métodos

Tags: java, profiling

Preciso criar uma classe para interceptar os métodos de uma determinada classe afim de monitorar o tempo de execução, para descobrir onde esta o gargalo de minhas transações.

Comment: Use ferramentas de profiling conforme informou o Bigown.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

O que você deseja é um software de [*profiling*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29).

Você não vai conseguir fazer algo diretamente no código que funcione corretamente e não traga outros problemas.

Alguns exemplos:

- [jMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html).
- [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/).
- [Java Mission Control](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html).
- [jProbe](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3659/beafr/index.html).
- [BTrace](https://kenai.com/projects/btrace).
- [EurekaJ](http://eurekaj.haagen.name/).
- [NetBeans](https://profiler.netbeans.org/).
- [JVMMonitor](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jvmmonitor/).
- [GCViewer](http://www.tagtraum.com/gcviewer.html).
- [Patty](http://patty.sourceforge.net/).
- [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).
- [JIP](http://jiprof.sourceforge.net/).
- [Profiller4j](http://profiler4j.sourceforge.net/).
- [jProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html).
- [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/).
- [XRebel](https://jrebel.com/software/xrebel/).

Cada um tem sua vantagem e utilidade mais específica. Existem diversas outras opções pagas e agora que sabe do que se trata pode buscar por conta própria.

Infelizmente a maioria não está facilmente acessível mais. Considere produtos praticamente abandonados, e os desconsidere, os use o nome para pesquisar e ver se vale a pena pro seu caso ainda insistir nele.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).